# multiple DNS queries in one web page request

Tags: c, proxy, web, dns

I am working on a web proxy.The logic is client sends request to proxy, proxy sends the same request to server, and sends the answer back to the client. 
   For example, i want to visit www.baidu.com. I get "Host:www.baidu.com" in the GET: package, which is used to send a dns request, then i get the ip of "www.baidu.com", establish the socket between proxy and server.
The question is when I use wireshark to  capture normal packages not with proxy, i find that there is more dns request queries visting "www.baidu.com" except query for www.baidu.com. It will query for nsclick.baidu.com and suggestion.baidu.com in different sockets.But there is no signal to let me to initiate these DNS queries, not like query for "www.baidu.com",in which i can initiate it when i detect "Host:". Can someone help me ? thank u.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how this should be working probably in first place.

Imagine i hit www.baidu.com in my browser, which sends traffic via your proxy. For your proxy currently, www.baidu.com is the only thing to lookup for.

When my browser end up receiving html chunk for this request, received html/js code then loads requests for some images which comes from nsclick.baidu.com. Similarly requests for other resources (css, js, images) can be made. In turn they all again go through your proxy and then their you will be doing your usual dns query.

Comment: I understand.I will check that and add some test for detecting these new addresses.

Comment: I think OP wants to know the needed hostnames in advance to prequery/precache them.

Comment: Each such DNS query is also (multiple) separate GET request(s)